# Where is plug-in "Color Ramp Manager"?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, color-ramp

I am following a tutorial on color-relief hillshades (found here: https://ieqgis.wordpress.com/2015/04/04/create-great-looking-topographic-maps-in-qgis-2/ )

The post is dated 2015-04-04, so - not that old.

The author says "superior colour ramps can be downloaded using Etienne Tourigny’s Color Ramp Manager (Plugins – Manage and Install Plugins)."

I cannot find this in the Plugin manager. It must be a current plugin, because there is a page for it at https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/colorrampmanager/ .

How can I find & install this plugin, please?

I am using QGIS 2.12 Lyon on a Mac running OS X 10.10.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to select "Show also experimental plugins" in the plugin manager settings, as the plugin is classified as experimental, as you can see below:

[image]

[image]